# I am receiving a "Variable does not exist: currentItem.Item_Family_Picklist__c" Error

Tags: apex, trigger, custom-object, custom-field, after-trigger

I am receiving a

> "Variable does not exist: currentItem.Item_Family_Picklist__c"

Error on my below trigger. I have verified the api name of the field and the correct object etc. the field exist.

The purpose of the trigger is so when a user types in a number into the Item_Group_input__c and the Item_Family_Input__c fields using specific values, the Item_Family_Picklist__c field should change to a specific value. These are predetermined values that will never change. The reason I did not use a formula field is because there will be about 105 values and If fieldx = xx && fieldy = xx change Fieldz = 'PicklistValue'  variations. that will go beyond the character limit in the formula field.

Please help, I am at a loss of what else I can try to fix this with.

```
trigger UpdateItemFamily on _Product__c (before insert, before update, after insert) {


    for(Product__c currentItem : trigger.new)


        if (currentItem.Item_Group_input__c == 10 && currentItem.Item_Family_input__c == 10 )

         currentItem.Item_Family_Picklist__c = 'Bananas';

    if (currentItem.Item_Group_input__c == 10 && currentItem.Item_Family_input__c == 20 )

         currentItem.Item_Family_Picklist__c = 'Citrus Fruits';

    if (currentItem.Item_Group_input__c == 10 && currentItem.Item_Family_input__c == 30 )

         currentItem.Item_Family_Picklist__c = 'Pome Fruits';

    if (currentItem.Item_Group_input__c == 10 && currentItem.Item_Family_input__c == 40 )

         currentItem.Item_Family_Picklist__c = 'Stone Fruits';

    if (currentItem.Item_Group_input__c == 10 && currentItem.Item_Family_input__c == 50 )

         currentItem.Item_Family_Picklist__c = 'Grapes ';

    if (currentItem.Item_Group_input__c == 10 && currentItem.Item_Family_input__c == 60 )

         currentItem.Item_Family_Picklist__c = 'Melons';

    if (currentItem.Item_Group_input__c == 10 && currentItem.Item_Family_input__c == 70 )

         currentItem.Item_Family_Picklist__c = 'Exotic Fruits';

    if (currentItem.Item_Group_input__c == 10 && currentItem.Item_Family_input__c == 80 )

         currentItem.Item_Family_Picklist__c = 'Berries';

    if (currentItem.Item_Group_input__c == 10 && currentItem.Item_Family_input__c == 90 )

         currentItem.Item_Family_Picklist__c = 'Dried Fruit';

}
```

Comment: Why don't you do this in a workflow rule or process builder?  It would be a lost easier.  That error means the field doesn't exist.  Is it maybe missing the namespace?  i.e. `ICIX_V1__Item_Family_Picklist__c` instead

Comment: @Nick Cook Thanks for the Response. The reason I went with a trigger is because I will be doing hundreds of values, statements etc. That is a lot to do in a workflow rule or even process builder. Secondly, I wanted to take into account the workflow rule limits that the org is already nearing. Process builder, I would need to include the process builder into the package for updates. which is not desired as this only affects one org. I tried the namespace and I get the same error. I have another trigger similar with no namespace in it and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you have no curly braces `{}` wrapping the content of your `for` loop.  This results in only the next line being part of the `for` loop.

e.g.

```
for(ICIX_V1__ICIX_Product__c currentItem : trigger.new)
{
    ... do stuff
}
```

Without the curly braces, only the first line is executed in the context of the `for` loop, and the `currentItem` variable only exists for the first line.

Comment: Ah, you're a smart man.  Thank you for the help I appreciate this greatly.